# Why is there one octahedral and two tetrahedral positions for every anion in a close packed structure?

Tags: crystal-structure

I'm reading about ionic crystal structures with planes of close-packed anions and the interstitial sites for cations. There are two types of interstitial sites: tetrahedral and octahedral. That makes perfect sense. What confuses me is this:

> for each of these anion spheres, one octahedral and two tetrahedral positions exist.

Where does this come from? It would seem that for every new anion sphere added, there is a single new tetrahedral position and a single new octahedral position.

Comment: Do you know how many octahedral sites and tetrahedral sites is a single "sphere" in contact with, when arranged in a closed packed structure with 12 co-ordinating spheres?